# Overloading the = operator for nullable types?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, nullable

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx) mentions that overloading the = operator is not possible.

How is it possible then for Nullable types to be assigned to null?

```
int? i = null;
```

Besides can I do it with my own generic types and how?

Comment: Its the implicit-conversion not the assignment-operator  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131346(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @rlesias I did post that a nullable type is a struct, but he is also right - the implicit cast operator is something that you can override yourself if you really want to.

Comment: @rlesias Ah, no problem - first posts on SO are always a little messy - everyone edits their answers and comments get confused! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is special compiler support for the `Nullable` type.

It is impossible to create a user-defined implicit conversion to/from `null`.  They built it into the language (and the runtime) rather than creating `Nullable` on top of the language, as so many BCL classes are made.

Interestingly this is not the only special support created for `Nullable`.  When you box a `Nullable<T>` it doesn't actually box a `Nullable` object, *ever*.  If `HasValue` is false, `null` is boxed, and if it's true, the underlying value is unwrapped and boxed.  It would be impossible to do this for your own type.

Answer (score 2):

It's the implicit-conversion not the assignment-operator that allows to assign `null`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131346(v=vs.110).aspx

> If the value parameter is **not null**, the Value property of the new
>   `Nullable<T>` value is initialized to the value parameter and the
>   `HasValue` property is initialized to `true`. If the value parameter is
>   **null**, the `Value` property of the new `Nullable<T>` value **is initialized
>   to the default value**, which is the value that is all binary zeroes,
>   and the `HasValue` property **is initialized to false.**

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what Tim's comment (Edit: And now answer =D) says - There's an implicit conversion from the null literal, rather than an overload of the assignment operator.

From the C# [language spec](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) (I was looking at Version 5.0) - Section `"6.1.5 Null literal conversions"`:

> An implicit conversion exists from the null literal to any nullable
>   type. This conversion produces the null value (§4.1.10) of the given
>   nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

Nullable types are instances of the struct

```
System.Nullable<T>.
```

The type that can be specified or made nullable is specified as the generic type of nullable (T).

More info here...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

In your example, you're not actually setting an int to null, rather setting the value on the struct which encapsulates it to null.